# Java 6 file.exists() and file.isFile() fail inexplicably

Tags: java, file-io

I'm working on a project that simulates a file repository, thus I'm using a lot of file operations. I'm developing it on a Windows8 machine, but it should be portable to other platforms as well. It is required that the project is written in Java 6. Consider the following code:

```
public void add(String description, boolean move, String repPath, String filePath) throws Exception {

    ...

    File fileToAdd = new File(filePath);
    if(!fileToAdd.exists()) throw new FileNotFoundException(filePath + " does not exist.");

    ...

    addDataset(description, move, repPath, fileToAdd, parentID);
    ...
}
```

The parameter `filePath` is a relative path to a file named `move.txt` (I've created this pretty standard text file my-self directly on the filesystem).

Now first of all, the `fileToAdd.exists()` check fails (let alone the fact, that this piece of code was not an issue for the last couple of weeks). But I am 100 % sure that the file does exist at this location. I printed out the absolute path, which appears to be the correct one, so I can't see why the check fails ... Also, `fileToAdd.canRead()` fails (I've tested this as sometimes this was working in similar posts I've reviewed). Also `fileToAdd.getAbsoluteFile().exists()` fails.

In order to test the rest of the code, I deleted this line temporarily and found another issue:

```
private void addDataset(String description, boolean move, String repPath, File datasetToAdd, long parentID) {

if(datasetToAdd.isFile()){

        addFile(description, move, repPath, datasetToAdd, parentID);

    } else {

        ...
    }
}
```

In this second snippet, the `datasetToAdd`-File object is the same as the `fileToAdd` from above, so it should indeed be a file (namely `move.txt`). But the `datasetToAdd.isFile()`-check fails! I've read in the javadoc, that this happens, if the file-object does not represent a directory (I'm pretty sure this is not the issue) or a "normal" file ... I did not find out, what an unnormal file is, but if a simple text-file is not normal, then what is?

Comment: Can you show what the file path is?  And relative is relative... relative to the JDK?  After you create the File object - do a print on absolute path to see where it thinks it's looking

Comment: The filepath is `C:\Users\Manuel\Desktop\move.txt`. When I tested it in Eclipse it was relative to the src-folder, but I also tested it via .jar, then it was relative to the location of the jar. I btw also tested it with absolute paths

Comment: If you hard code in the file path does it work?

Comment: No: `File fileToAdd = new File("C:\\Users\\Manuel\\Desktop\\move.txt");` did not work either

Comment: @Stringerbell please do Bohemian's test: `System.out.println(fileToAdd.getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: @fvu I've done this already (see post and comment on Bohemian's post)

Comment: How about : String fs = System.getProperty("path.separator");  File fileToAdd = new File("C:" +fs + "Users" + fs + "Manuel" + fs + "Desktop" + fs + "move.txt");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time there's a question like "java can't find the file... I know it's there!", it *isn't* there, because:

**The current directory of the JVM is not what you think it is.**

The fastest way to debug is:

```
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

And you'll quickly see why java "can't find" the file.

Comment: Not always. Incorrect usage of \ is also fun on non-Windows.  I have also used a platform which allowed a "C:" directory.  Especially fun when trying to access that folder on a windows shared drive.

Comment: I did check the absolute path as I wrote in my post. I also tested it with absolute paths, copy-pasting the path from the explorer into the main parameters ... same problem

Comment: @StringerBell - did you check the permissions?  is the java programming running with the same user that you are checking the file from?

Comment: @jtahlborn Both System and my User have full permissions on the file. Both the eclipse and java platform process are run by my user - is this what you meant?

Comment: Try using forward slashes instead of backslashes. If that doesn't work, try seeing if the directory is there, then if it is listing all files in the directory. Keep going back up the directory structure looking for where the problem is.

Comment: @Bohemian It did not change anything - but it helped me find the issue! The name of the file was not in fact `move.txt` but `move.txt.txt`, but my settings in the explorer do not show the format - so my bad after all.